# Why is the function storing zeros when I try to populate an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to Java, soon I will start a course but at the moment I'm studying alone.
I made a function to check if a number is a prime number, then, if it is, I'm trying to store the values in an int array with a for loop.
The function is working in detecting prime numbers, but when storing the values I get multiple 0's in the array.
I cannot understand why and I couldn't find any answer online.
This is the code

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Exercises {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int [] array = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            if (isPrime(i))
                array[i] = i;

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n){

        if(n <= 1)
            return false;

        for(int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++)
            if(n % i == 0)
                return false;

            return true;
    }
}
```

The result I have from this is
[0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0]

while I would like to have
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]

I also checked with a visualizer but still cannot understand why is behaving like that.
Thank you for your time

Comment: `array[i] = i;` <- Your assignment is assigning i to index i. Why would you expect anything else than what your re seeing with this behaviour? It can assign 0 to index 0, 1 to index 0, 2 to index 2 etc. pp. But never ever will that line lead to assigning 2 to index 0 like you expect it to

Answer (score 3):

```
array[i] = i;
```

You are assigning values only to the prime indices of the array - i.e. you assign `2` to `array[2]`, `3` to `array[3]`, etc...

The values of all the other indices of the array remain `0` by default.

If you want to assign to all the indices of the array, you need a second variable to track the current available index of the array.

I suggest using a `while` loop instead of `for` loop, since it's not sufficient to iterate over the indices of the array.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
int num = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
    if (isPrime(num)) {
        array[i] = num;
        i++;
    }
    num++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Now the output will be

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```